# Codeigniter obtener valores de un input o una variable desde el controlador

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

Soy nuevo en codeigniter y queria saber si se puede obtener el valor de una etiqueta input o de una variable de php desde el controlador. Lo que quiero lograr es mandar datos de una visata a otra de manera similar al metodo POST (sin que los valores sean visibles en la URL)

Por ejemplo:

Vista 1:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="valueInput">
   <?php $valueVaraible = "Ejemplo" ?>
   <a type="button" href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/Welcome/toView2">Redirigir a vista 2</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
public function toView2() {
    $this->load->helper('array');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $arrayData = array(
        'valueInput' => "algun metodo para otener el valor del input", 
        'valueVaraible'=>"algun metodo para otener el valor de la variable");

    $this->load->view('view2', $arrayData);
}
```

Comment: Hi.. the official language of the site is spanish. If spanish is your first language, please translate the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es un formulario para poder enviar los datos que deseas por POST y en tu controlador recibirlo con el apoyo de la clase [Input](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html). Como lo muestro en el siguiente código:

View:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/Welcome/toView2" method="POST">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="valueInput" name="valueInput" value="Algún valor">
    <?php $valueVaraible = "Ejemplo" ?>
    <!--Enviar otros valores que no se muestran en el formulario -->
    <input type="hidden" id="valueInput" name="valueInput" value="<?php echo $valueVaraible ?>">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function toView2() {
    $this->load->helper('array');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $arrayData = array(
        'valueInput' => $this->input->post('valueInput'), 
        'valueVaraible'=>$this->input->post('valueVaraible'));

    $this->load->view('view2', $arrayData);
}
```

Aqui te dejo la [documentación oficial](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Mejor usa el helper de codeigniter

En tu vista tendras:

```
<?php echo form_open("controlador/metodo"); ?> 
  <input placeholder="txtNombre" type="text" name="nombre">
  <input placeholder="txtApaterno" type="text" name="apellido">
  <input placeholder="txtAmaterno" type="text" name="apellido">
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<?php
$msj = (isset($msj)) ? $msj:validation_errors();
if (strlen($msj) > 0 )
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'><h1 class='text-center'> <a href='".site_url("cliente")."'>Atras</a> |  $msj  </h1></div>";

?>
```

y en tu controlador vas a tener:

```
<?php

public function index(){
  //Se cargan los helpers y librerias de codeigniter
  //que nos facilitan algunas cosas.
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
}

public function frm_alta()
{
  //Cliente es mi controlador, y frm_alta es mi vista frm_alta.php
  $this->load->view("Cliente/frm_alta");
}

public function agregar()
{
  //validacion de los campos, puedes leer sobre esto aqui:
  //https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

  $this->form_validation->set_rules("txtNombre", "Nombre", "trim|required");
  $this->form_validation->set_rules("txtApaterno", "Apaterno", "trim");
  $this->form_validation->set_rules("txtAmaterno", "Amaterno", "trim");
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

      $this->load->model("Modelocliente");

      $insert = $this->Modelocliente->agregar(
          $this->input->post("txtNombre"),
          $this->input->post("txtApaterno"),
          $this->input->post("txtAmaterno")
      );
      if ($insert > 0) {
          $this->data["msj"] = "Cliente agregado";
          $b = 1;
      } else {
          $this->data["msj"] = "Error al realizar el proceso";
      }
  } else {
      $this->frm_alta();
  }

  } //FIN DE LA FUNCION

?>
```

Y ya por ultimo en tu Modelo deberias de tener:

```
function agregar($nombre,$apaterno,$amaterno)
{
  $array = array("idCliente"=>0,
                  "Nombre"=>$nombre,
                  "Apaterno"=>$apaterno,
                  "Amaterno"=>$amaterno
              );
  $this->db->insert("Cliente",$array);
  return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Espero te sirva mi ejemplo, lo tenia mas complejo por asi decirlo pero lo simplifique para que entiendas bien como funciona Codeigniter, de paso te recomiendo leer el manual :) no es tan complicado como otros frameworks